# .NET 5 WEB API not returning response in postman and browser

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

.NET 5 WEB API not returning response in postman and browser. Please help me to resolve this issue.
Here is the code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using RestSharp;

namespace WebAPIApplication.Controllers
{
    [Route("api")]
    [ApiController]
    [Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
    [Consumes(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
    public class ApiController : ControllerBase
    {


        [HttpGet("public")]
        public IActionResult myPublic()
        {
            MyStatus _status = new MyStatus();
            return Ok(_status);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the response:
{}

Comment: I can't see MyStatus class and what url have you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `return Ok(_status);`

> Here is the response: `{}`

Please check and make sure you defined properties well in your class `MyStatus`, perhaps you defined them as fields not properties, which cause this issue.

```
public class MyStatus
{
    public int StatusCode;
    //...
```

*To fix the issue, can modify it as below*

```
public class MyStatus
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    //...
```